# Multiple Intents tied to one button in appwidget?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-appwidget, android-pendingintent

In an appwidget in android, is there a way to set multiple pending intents to one button? Currently, it's only recognizing the last intent I declare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In an appwidget in android, is there a way to set multiple pending intents to one button?

No, sorry. Only one on-click `PendingIntent` per `View`.

Comment: What's the best way then to get multiple intents processed onclick?

Comment: @Matt: You don't, any more than you get multiple `OnClickListeners` with a `Button` in an activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can link the pending intent to fire off an intent for next one when its done with its work, that's how I do it.  I have a widget that fires a pendingIntent to launch a service which in turn fires off another Intent when it's done.  Alternatively, you can have the pendingIntent launch a service that spawns multiple intents.